# Вывод произвольных типов записей вместе с обычными записями (post)

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как можно выводить произвольный тип записей вместе в обычными записями?
Т.е. имеется уже готовый сайт на wp с обычными типами постов.
Теперь нужно создать новый тип постов, и выводить эти новые записи вместе с обычными постами.
Как это можно сделать без плагинов?
Как создать новый тип постов я знаю. Интересует именно то, как добавить эти новые посты к обычным постам?

Comment: Добавить условие в цикле вывода

Comment: а подскажите, какое условие?

Answer (score 0):

```
'post_type' => array( 'post', 'custom_post' )
```

На всякий случай: [WP_Query](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#znakomstvo-s-wp_query)